# Make Bootstrap-table from tabular to Data Card View when screen resize?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello StackOverflow I am working with:

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

The problem is this when a screen size is desktop i have data-card-view="false", but when the screen size is a mobile or on resize the screen I want to change the property data-card-view="false" to data-card-view="true" and get the version of data-card-view. The problem is than i change it with jquery but the table does not change in the fly.

How can I achieve that without refresh all the page?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that: [bootstrap-table-mobile](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code. in bottom of your Html.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $table = $('#fresh-table'),
       full_screen = false;
var windowsize = $(window).width();
function checkWidth() {
   windowsize = $(window).width();
   if (windowsize >= 440) {
//Get the cardView 
       var data = JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable('getOptions'));
       var CardData = JSON.parse(data).cardView;
       if (CardData == true) {
           $table.bootstrapTable('toggleView');
       }
        $table.bootstrapTable({
            cardView: false,
        });
        $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');

    }
    else {
        var data = JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable('getOptions'));
        var CardData = JSON.parse(data).cardView;
        if (CardData == false) {
            $table.bootstrapTable('toggleView');
        }
        $table.bootstrapTable({
            cardView: true,
        });
    }
    $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');

}
    checkWidth();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        checkWidth();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the [display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) that bootstrap provides.

Create a table view and a card view.

Then use

`<div class="row d-none d-sm-block ">` to wrap your table to show the table on a large or medium screen

and `<div class="row d-sm-none">` to wrap your card to show on mobile